# Webtest - Using Dates as Context Parameters

Tags: c#, datetime, load-testing, web-performance

I've created a webtest and have a CSV data source that contains a column with a list of short dates (MM/dd/yyyy)

I need to manipulate the parameter due to part of the web page I'm testing has a form parameter that needs it to be formatted as **yyyyMMdd**

When the date that is captured from the data source (ex: 02/12/2016), I noticed in the Context tab of my test run that the format to "2/12/2016 12:00:00 AM"

I've created a Request plug-in and added the following code:

```
public override void PreRequest(object sender, PreRequestEventArgs e)
{
   base.PreRequest(sender e)

   string CSVDate = e.WebTest.Context["<datasource date column>"].ToString();
   DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(CSVDate, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   e.WebTest.Context.Add("NewDate", dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));

}
```

This generates a **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime** error.  I tried changing the format to *MM/dd/yyyy*, but I encountered the same error.

Does anyone know how the correct DateTime format I should be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date-time as shown in the context is `2/12/2016 12:00:00 AM`. This has only one digit for the month whereas the format specifier has `MM` which wants two digits. The date-time also contains the letters `AM` that are not matched by the format.

Modifying the format to be `M/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` matches the date-time `2/12/2016 12:00:00`, but does not match the `AM` part. In theory the `tt` format specifier should match this, but it did not work for me.

Rather than using `ParseExact` you can use `Parse` and it works out the correct format. Using the following worked on the date-time string provided:

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(CSVDate, new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

The `CultureInfo` is needed because the input date has the month and the days the wrong way around.

However, the real problem is in the way CSV files are handled by the web test. It appears to read them using the same logic as Microsoft Excel uses when reading CSVs. Namely, if it looks like a date then convert it to a date. So any string matching `dd/dd/dddd` (where `d` is a digit) might be connverted to a date. (E.g. `15/15/2017` will not be converted because `15` is not a month number.) I recommend rewriting the CSV to format the input date differently, use something that Excel would not treat as a date. One option is to have the date in three columns of the CSV, so have explicit `day,`month`and`year`columns. Another option is to add non-date characters to the string and format it correctly, eg as`z20160212`and then remove the`z`within the web test. Generally, I would advise to avoid the conversion of string to`DateTime` then another conversion to a different string.

Comment: DateTime.Parse ended up being the better option for me to use.  It looks like to me that rewriting the CSV would involve touching each of the dates because it's provided with the format set to short date.  Changing the format converts the column cells to a 5-digit number.  Appreciate the help!